# Loading animation in jquery

Tags: php

I have an anchor link in my webpage. I have written a PHP file to make the ZIP few files and to download it. Here I have given the link as below.

```
<a href="externalfile.php?id=100">Make A Zip</a>
```

Actually, it is taking much of time to make a ZIP and download. So I would like to put some animation there. 
Can I show an animation image while page rounding when I clicks on the link "Make A Zip" ? Please share suggetions...

Any Suggestions please??
Thanks
Sateesh

Comment: Post your code here...

Comment: <a href="externalfile.php?id=100">Make A Zip</a>

Answer (score 0):

```
For that purpose you can use jquery mobile loadingmaessage or otherwise you can use custom image with animation.



  $(document).on('pagebeforecreate', '#index', function(){     
    var interval = setInterval(function(){
$.mobile.loading( 'show', {
    text: 'foo',
    textVisible: true,
    theme: 'z',
    html: ""
});
        clearInterval(interval);
    },1);    
});

$(document).on('pageshow', '#index', function(){  
    var interval = setInterval(function(){
$.mobile.loading( 'show', {
    text: 'foo',
    textVisible: true,
    theme: 'z',
    html: ""
});
        clearInterval(interval);
    },1);      
});
```

In HTML page include jquery mobile libraries ,you can give jquerymobile CDN from the jquerymobile.com website.After that,add the above code inside script tag odf the HTML page.

Comment: Thanks for the responce, but here I am not understanding how to use above code you given. Can you please say some more information. Thanks for your time.

Comment: This is web application and I have given anchor tag in the web page.<a href="externalfile.php?id=100">Make A Zip</a>.